# iOS web app links refresh entire page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone-web-app

I have a website that uses Bootstrap3 and mvc5.  Its full responsive but wanted to add a little something extra with the ability to save to home page and present it as a web app.

I did all the correct head tags

```
<meta name="apple-touch-fullscreen" content="yes">
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
```

and added the javascript from https://github.com/stylr/iosweblinks to prevent the a links from opening in safari.

The issue i have is when a link is called it refreshes the entire page.  The top nav menu refreshes and reloads every time.  It looks like crap.  When in safari it doesnt do that.  Its nice and smooth.

Has anyone experienced this?

Comment: maybe you can file an issue/question on its repo? https://github.com/stylr/iosweblinks/issues

Comment: Its beyond just the iosweblinks... ive tried multiple javascript and jquery suggestions from multiple threads and they all do the same thing.   Im curious if anyone else has had this issue

Comment: @JoeyD I have the same issue.  Trying various things to prevent it.  No luck yet :-/.  I don't even use iosweblinks in my web apps either.

Comment: Thanis @Entrabiter.  I have yet to find a solution to this and its driving me nuts.  Its blocking me from launching a mobile wrapped version of my site.